# Python: Iterate over each item in nested-list-of-lists and replace specific items

Tags: python, python-2.7, nested-lists

I am a beginner in python. I want to know if there is any in-built function or other way so I can achieve below in python 2.7:

Find all **-letter** in list and sublist and replace it with **['not',letter]**

Eg: Find all items in below list starting with - and replace them with ['not',letter]

```
Input : ['and', ['or', '-S', 'Q'], ['or', '-S', 'R'], ['or', ['or', '-Q', '-R'], '-S']]
Output : ['and', ['or', ['not','S'], 'Q'], ['or', ['not','S'], 'R'], ['or', ['or', ['not','Q'], ['not','R']], ['not','S']]]
```

Can anyone suggest how to do it in python.
Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try a bit of recursion:

```
def change(lol):
    for index,item in enumerate(lol):
        if isinstance(item, list):
            change(item)
        elif item.startswith('-'):
            lol[index] = ['not',item.split('-')[1]]
    return lol
```

In action:

```
In [24]: change(['and', ['or', '-S', 'Q'], ['or', '-S', 'R'], ['or', ['or', '-Q', '-R'], '-S']])
Out[24]:
['and',
['or', ['not', 'S'], 'Q'],
['or', ['not', 'S'], 'R'],
['or', ['or', ['not', 'Q'], ['not', 'R']], ['not', 'S']]]
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to use a recursive function.The `isinstance(item, str)` simply checks to see if an item is string.

```
def dumb_replace(lst):
     for ind, item in enumerate(lst):
         if isinstance(item, str):
             if item.startswith('-'):
                 lst[ind] = ['not', 'letter']
         else:
             dumb_replace(item)
```

And:

```
dumb_replace(Input)
```

Gives:

```
['and', ['or', ['not', 'letter'], 'Q'], ['or', ['not', 'letter'], 'R'], ['or', ['or', ['not', 'letter'], ['not', 'letter']], ['not', 'letter']]]
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on a recipe found [here](http://arstechnica.com/civis/viewtopic.php?f=20&t=1120489):

```
def nested_list_replacer(seq, val = '-S', sub = ['not', 'letter']):
    def top_kill(s):
        for i in s:
            if isinstance(i, str):
                if i == val:
                    i = sub
                yield i
            else:                
                yield type(i)(top_kill(i))

    return type(seq)(top_kill(seq))        


l = ['and', ['or', '-S', 'Q'], ['or', '-S', 'R'], ['or', ['or', '-Q', '-R'], '-S']]
print(nested_list_replacer(l, '-S'))
print(nested_list_replacer(l, '-Q'))
```

Gives:

```
['and', ['or', ['not', 'letter'], 'Q'], ['or', ['not', 'letter'], 'R'], ['or', ['or', '-Q', '-R'], ['not', 'letter']]]
['and', ['or', '-S', 'Q'], ['or', '-S', 'R'], ['or', ['or', ['not', 'letter'], '-R'], '-S']]
```